# GIDSignIn current user is nil after restorePreviousSignIn()

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-oauth, gidsignin

My issue here is that: This shared instance is called

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn()
```

But when I try to check the current user it remains nil after the call.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser != nil
```

I would assume I may need a proper delay before checking if the user is nil or not. How can I properly add a delay or populate the user before checking if the user is nil.

ex: confirming that **GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn()**   has finished before checking **GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser**

```
 if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.hasPreviousSignIn() && GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser == nil) {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn()    
        }else{
                print("user has no shared instance. User has not been prev signed in")
        }
        
        
        
        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser != nil) {
         }else{
               print("user is nil")
        }
```

Using GoogleSignIn SDK
[GoogleSignIn Framework Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you studied at the documentation you linked you'd be able to see the `restorePreviousSiginin` is asynchronous and also know how to use it.

> `func restorePreviousSignIn(callback: GIDSignInCallback? = nil)`
>
> *callback*
> The GIDSignInCallback block that is called on completion. This block will be called asynchronously on the main queue.

where the completion handler is defined as:

> `typealias GIDSignInCallback = (GIDGoogleUser?, Error?) -> Void`

You should use the completion handler to process the result of trying to restore the previous sign in, not try to do it synchronously in the method.  Something like

```
if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.hasPreviousSignIn() && GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser == nil) {
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn() { 
    user, error in
    if let user = user {
      print(user)  // handle the user info
    } else {
       print(error ?? "unknown error")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the documentation and resolving my issue.